# Hitting time of a stochastically continuous process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $X$ is 1-d stochastically continuous process with $X(0) = 0$, i.e.
$X_s \to X_t$ in probability as $s\to t$ for all $t\ge 0$. Let $\tau = \inf\{t>0: |X_t|>1\}$.

[Q.] Is $\tau>0$ almost surely?

I think the answer shall be yes, because $X$ has a Cadlag version (modification).
Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with the process $X_t=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider some random sequence that converges to $0$ a.s., for example, $Y_n=(Z_1+\cdots+ Z_n)^{-1}$, where $Z$'s are i.i.d. (for instance) Exp(1) random variables. Set 
$$
X_t = \begin{cases}
       2, & \text{if $t=Y_k$ for some $k$},\\
       0, &\text{otherwise}.
      \end{cases}
$$
Then $X$ is stochastically continuous (since $X_t=0$ a.s. for any fixed $t$), but $\tau=0$ a.s.

Comment: Thanks for this cute example. I am considering a Levy jump process, ex. $\alpha$-stable process for $\alpha = 3/2$. Is $\tau>0$ a.s.? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a specialist in Levy processes   :)

Comment: For $\alpha$-stable process, it seems to me yes. From scaling property, for any $c>0$, we have $\max_{0\le t <c} |X_t| \sim c^{1/\alpha} \max_{0\le t <1} |X_t|$. This implies $P(\max_{0\le t <c} |X_t| <1) = P(\max_{0\le t <1} |X_t| < c^{-1/\alpha}) \to 1$ as $c\to 0$. Thus, $P(\tau>0) \ge P(\tau\ge c) = P(\max_{0\le t <c} |X_t| <1)  \to 1$ as $c\to 1$. Thanks for your help.